# Memory error in python using tkinter when reading multiple files whose total size add upto 1.4 GB, trying to search a specific data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, file-handling

I am trying to **upload multiple files in python using Tkinter GUI** but the problem is when the **maximum limit reaches around 1GB** then python gives memory error following is the code I am using to read multiple files and I am appending it to one list though I have tried creating list of list then also I am getting **memory error**, I don't know how to read such big files in python

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog 
from tkinter import simpledialog


def browse():
   files=filedialog.askopenfilenames(parent=root,title='Choose a file')
   lst=list(files)
   lines=[]
   for i in lst:
      f=open(i,'r')
      lines+=f.readlines()
      f.close()
   print(lines)
root=Tk()
root.geometry("")
# some lines of code irrevelant for this question
B=Button(root,text="Click here for input  files ",command=browse).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

**And When I am trying to upload a file of size 1.4GB it's giving following error , how to resolve it is the maximum file size limit for python is 1GB only?**
**

```
Error
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback(most recent call last):
  lines+=(f.readlines())
Memory Error
```

**

Comment: If you only have 1GB of memory available, then the answer is that you *don't* read files of size 1.4GB.  But do you actually need them all in memory at once?  The text of your Button suggests that the data will be uploaded somewhere, rather than processed - that only implies reading a small chunk of data at a time, from a single file at a time.

Comment: yes I need them in memory at once because I need to search some specific text in those file for which I am using regex (which is absolutely working fine) if files read is successful, let me edit the text so that confusion which you got also eradicates

Comment: Why can't you use the regex on smaller chunks of the file?

Comment: Yes @JohnColeman we can use it but how to code it , what I find till now that using multiprocessing we can do it can you give any example like for me the case I want to search particular data from multiple files but i don't know How to do it?